# HackerRank Project Euler #1 Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'currently training Kotlin using Project Euler based programming challenges on HackeRank.

Today I have been working on the first challenge:

[image]

My first solution was:

```
import java.util.Scanner


fun main() {
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)

    val numberOfInputs = sc.nextInt()

    val inputs = IntArray(numberOfInputs)
    for (index in 0 until numberOfInputs) {
        inputs[index] = sc.nextInt()
    }

    for (input in inputs) {
        var sum = 0

        for (number in 3 until input) {
            if (number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0){
                sum += number
            }
        }

        println(sum)
    }
}
```

This version of the program still fails HackerRank test cases for exceeding time limits!
So I need to optimize code further and I tried again with another solution:

```
import java.util.*


private fun triangleNumber(n : Int) : Int {
    return n*(n+1)/2
}

private fun s3(n : Int) : Int {
    return 3 * triangleNumber(n/3)
}

private fun s5(n : Int) : Int {
    return 5 * triangleNumber(n/5)
}

private fun s15(n : Int) : Int {
    return 15 * triangleNumber(n/15)
}

fun main() {
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)

    val numberOfInputs = sc.nextInt()

    for (index in 0 until numberOfInputs) {
        val input = sc.nextInt() - 1

        println(s3(input) + s5(input) - s15(input))
    }
}
```

based on the following article: https://medium.com/@TheZaki/project-euler-1-multiples-of-3-and-5-c24cb64071b0

This version of the program is failing 2 test cases for "Wrong Answer" but i cannot figure out why.

I think there is something magic about Python on how numbers are rounded or something like that!

Comment: What is the failing test case? Where is the [mcve]? Isn't there a topic that better describes the problem you're having? Please, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The test case is hidden, if i could see the test case failing i could have probably been able to figure out why it is not working myself :)

Comment: That's exactly why those challenges make bad questions here.

Comment: I see, thank you Ulrich for the useful links btw!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the operation n*(n+1) with an high value of n was producing a value out of integer range.

Here the working solution

```
import java.util.Scanner

private fun triangleNumber(n : Int) : Long {
    val ln = n.toLong()

    return ln*(ln+1)/2
}

private fun s3(n : Int) : Long {
    return 3 * triangleNumber(n/3)
}

private fun s5(n : Int) : Long {
    return 5 * triangleNumber(n/5)
}

private fun s15(n : Int) : Long {
    return 15 * triangleNumber(n/15)
}

fun main() {
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)

    val numberOfInputs = sc.nextInt()

    for (index in 0 until numberOfInputs) {
        val input = sc.nextInt() - 1

        println(s3(input) + s5(input) - s15(input))
    }
}
```